# Why won't PrintWriter work?

Tags: java, file-writing

Here's my code:

```
public class Logger {
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    public Logger() {
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(Logger.class.getResource("/logs/logs.txt").getFile());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void log(String message) {
        message = "[LOG] : " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + " - " + message;
        System.out.println(message);
        writer.println(message);
    }

    public void p(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public void close() {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

I have been having problems with writing to files. The code above is all that is happening - log is called, then, at the end of the program's execution, close is called. I have experimented with adding a flush() at the end of the log, but that did nothing. The file definitely exists and it is definitely writable, it just seems that no matter what I do nothing happens in terms of saving it. I am on Eclipse and the log is located in a separate source folder, if that matters. I have tried refreshing Eclipse before and after writing and it makes no difference.

Comment: Resources are not files and cannot be written to. `PrintWriter` swallows exceptions, which you need to check for separately.

Comment: I see that you have a `close` method that wraps around the `writer`'s close method. Are you calling it? I don't think it writes a file unless you close the writer.

Comment: That's it! I also changed to a bufferedwriter. New code for readers:
    `writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("data/logs/logs.txt").getAbsolutePath()));`
And yes I was calling it like I say in the question